# Captured image file from PiCamera is 0kb, why?

Tags: pi-3, python, image

I use the following code to capture an image from PiCamera:

```py
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
```

When I run the code, an image file is created on desktop but its size is 0KB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works on my Pi3. What does 'ls ~/Desktop/image.jpg -l' show ?

Comment: Are you able to capture images successfully using the `raspistill` command?

Comment: Yes everything is OK with raspistill for capture the image. But with python code the file has no information.(0Byte)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created an object for the captured information to go to. Generally speaking, I think it's easier for beginners to learn the file method (as opposed to streams). The code below is an example taken from [readthedocs.io](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-stream), and should help you get started.

from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

```
# Explicitly open a new file called my_image.jpg
my_file = open('my_image.jpg', 'wb')

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
camera.capture(my_file)

# At this point my_file.flush() has been called, but the file has
# not yet been closed
my_file.close()
```

Comment: I cpied the following code in my Cam0.py  :   /   from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera# Explicitly open a new file called my_image.jpg
my_file = open('my_image.jpg', 'wb')
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
camera.capture(my_file)
# At this point my_file.flush() has been called, but the file has
# not yet been closed
my_file.close()                       
     /   after run the file is empty (Image file '/home/pi/Desktop/Babak/my_image.jpg' contains no data) !!!